# Chrome and Firefox handle background-blend-mode and mix-blend-mode differently

Tags: css

[image: Left is Chrome (intended effect) Right is Firefox]

I want to make the one on the right look like the one on the left, preferrably without using `<video>`. Here's the demo in question: http://tools.videblu.com/csgotaunts/dev/bg.html

Here's the relevant markup

```
<body>
    <div id="bg"></div>
</body>
```

---

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url('img/5.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

#bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('img/15.png');
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#bg:before, #bg:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('img/11.png');
    background-size: auto 2560px;
    background-blend-mode: soft-light;
}
#bg:before {
    animation: smoke1 180s linear 0s infinite;
}
#bg:after {
    animation: smoke2 200s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

Basically, I've got a colorful image as a background on `body`. I've made a div with a noisy background, and layered a smoke image `:before` and `:after` said div. `background-blend-mode` on chrome works the same way as `mix-blend-mode` on firefox.

Comment: Hm, could it maybe have something to do with vendor prefix?
`-webkit-animation: smoke2 200s linear 0s infinite;
         animation: smoke2 200s linear 0s infinite;`

Just a shot in the dark to be honest.

Comment: The animation has nothing to do with the blend mode. I can entirely remove animation/transition and the appearance will stay the same.